# Put Jar file into a folder and package as zip

Tags: java, maven, jar, directory, zip

Oracle Identity Manager application needs plugins to be deployed as I explained below:
There must be a zip file contains 2 folders and plugin.xml
folder structure is looks like this:

[image]

lib folder must contain project itself packaged as jar, META-INF folder must contain pluginPostProcessEventhandler.xml
This folders and file structure needs to be zipped as **pluginPostProcessEventhandler.zip** to be deployed. Using Jenkins. is there any way creating this folder and file structure as output folder by using pom.xml?
Thanks

Comment: I don't really understand the down-votes here. Questions about how to get Maven to build package with a particular structure seem to me to be valid programming questions. I rather suspect that it won't be possible, unless Maven has a particular plug-in to generate the required package. But that doesn't make it a bad question.

Answer (score 0):

With the Maven assembly plugin, it should be possible to create a zip in the way you describe.